# Can logging too frequently cause increase in heap size sharply?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, log4j, resource-leak

I am investigating an abrupt memory hike happening in a java process. I see that the heap size is growing till 3-4 GB. Upon investigating, i see that in a class, a logging is happening(which is very frequent, like, in every 1 or 2 ms) which is producing around 4MB of logs in 1 sec. So according to me, this is the cause for increase in heap size. Also the heap size doesn't decrease after the code comes out of the class and the logging stops. The process is using log4j-1.2.16.jar.

I have below questions.

1. Is log4j creating too many objects on the heap because of frequent logging? If yes, is it the expected behavior or is it some limitation in log4j which is solved in log4j2?
2. Why is the heap size not decreasing? Is log4j holding reference to the objects on the heap as they are not getting collected by GC?

Please help me in understanding this behavior of log4j and jvm. I don't know if this is a known thing and log4j2 has addressed it.

Answer (score 2):

[Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) is marked as end of life so upgrading to newer release is a good idea. Writing a large amount of log file can lead to performance issues depending on how you use the logging API, but you should still be able to resolve some logging issues without upgrading.

Review the messages and check the level of detail. A key problem is printing too many messages or code which does not to check the logging level, as the string expression gets evaluated even if the message is not needed. This can be the cause of high and unnecessary memory allocations. Consider:

```
logger.debug("This line causes memory allocations even if not printed: " +value);
```

If you changed logging level to `WARN`, the above String concatenation for the message still gets executed, and if `value.toString()` is an expensive memory operation there will be even more unnecessary object allocations in addition to StringBuilder calls added by the JVM. Change your log4j calls to check the level before logging:

```
if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
    logger.debug("The value is: " +value);
}
logger.debug("No need to call logger.isDebugEnabled() for a string literal");
```

With log4j2 you can log with format strings or `Supplier<String>`, and String concatenations for log message are only evaluated when the message is required.

Writing to System.out can be expensive, so make sure only INFO messages appear in console and use an appender so DEBUG messages go to log files.